# Mysql query when a condition valids then extract string

Tags: mysql, string

I have several fields containing the following contents. I want my query meets all the following fields but with the following conditions:

- First, when there are `dot` and `vipout` or `vipin` in fields just extract
  the string in between, I mean in case of `vipin3601.ym.ms` extract
  `3601` and in case of the `vipoutxxp1.ym.ms` extract `xxp1`.
- Sec, in rest of the condition just pick up whatever exists.

  ```
   select provider from test group by provider;
      +------------------+
      | provider   |
      +------------------+
      | 360-lay     |
      | 382Com           |
      | e-gus           |
      | e-ggg-inbound   |
      | ttthts           |
      | inefthyther        |
      | jfc              |
      | kefdfoo           |
      | vipin3601.ym.ms  |
      | vipinstm.ym.ms   |
      | vipout382.ym.ms  |
      | vipoutils2.ym.ms |
      | vipoutiot.ym.ms  |
      | vipoutxxp1.ym.ms |
      | vipoutqlm.ym.ms  |
      | vipoutspm.ym.ms  |
      | unknown          |
      +------------------+
      18 rows in set (0.00 sec)
  ```

I have tried something like:

```
select  left(provider,locate('.',provider)-1) from test group by provider;
```

But this returns as below and this is not what I want. I don't know how to change it to have the desired results.

```
 vipin3601 vipinstm vipout382 vipoutils vipoutiot vipoutxxp vipoutqlm vipoutspm
```

Thank you for any helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically going to need to build out a complex case statement here.  That might look like:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    /* vipin case */
    WHEN provider LIKE 'vipin%.%'
        /* grab substring up to first '.'
         * then get substring of that starting at 6th position
         * to accomodate for 5 letters in 'vipin'
         */
        THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(provider, '.', 1), 6)
    /* vipout case */
    WHEN provider LIKE 'vipout%.%'
        /* grab substring up to first '.'
         * then get substring of that starting at 6th position
         * to accomodate for 6 letters in 'vipout'
         */
        THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(provider, '.', 1), 7)
    /* all other cases */
    ELSE provider
  END AS result
FROM test
```

Note that I did not include your `GROUP BY` clause as it does not seem to do anything here, since there are no aggregation functions being used.

Comment: thank you for your answer! What is the `END AS result`? why we need to write it?

Comment: @MaryamPashmi The `END` is necessary to end the `CASE` statement.  The `AS result` part is just to provide an alias for the resulting field.  This aliasing is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN provider LIKE 'vipin%.%' 
             THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(provider, '.', 1), 'vipin', -1) 
          WHEN provider LIKE 'vipout%.%' 
             THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(provider, '.', 1), 'vipout', -1) 
       END
FROM test
WhERE provider LIKE 'vipin%.%' OR provider LIKE 'vipout%.%'
```